# Pandas: Subtrair datas em agrupados em índices em um dataframe

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

eu estou realizando uma pesquisa utilizando pandas e preciso inferir o horário entre dois ônibus baseados em seus horários de começo(start_time). Para isso eu tenho agrupados no meu dataframe um campo para itinerário e leg(otp_itinerary_id e otp_leg_id,respectivamente). E os horários dos ônibus estão sempre nas legs pares.

Então eu queria ajuda para realizar uma subtração dos bt_start_time das legs pares.

Segue na imagem maiores detalhes.
Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço bastante.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, pode ser feito percorrendo a tabela com o método `itertuples()` da seguinte maneira:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('suaPlanilha.xlsx')

for row in df.itertuples():
    if row.leg % 2 == 0:
        print(row.start_time2 - row.start_time1 )
```

Comment: obrigado @murilo-portugal consegui aplicar o itertuples ao contexto do meu problema e consegui resolve-lo.